# How to re add .classpath in intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I accidentally delete my `.classpath` for my intellij project.

It is causing the following error when I run my main

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

I tried manually adding it back, but the error still happens.

What is the recommended way to reconstruct `.classpath` in intellij

Comment: Intellij doesn't have a. classpath file. There are iml files!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your src `folder -> Mark Directory as -> Source Root`